# How to write Redux reducer for React Hooks component using typescript?

Tags: typescript, redux, types, react-hooks, typescript-typings

I'm trying to build typings for a redux-like reducer. But there is a strange problem with using typescript enum as index for mapped interface.

```js
// possible action types
enum ActionType {
  UpdateInterval,
  None,
  Test
}

// mapping interface [action-type]: data-type
interface ActionData {
  [ActionType.UpdateInterval]: Interval;
  [ActionType.None]: undefined,
  [ActionType.Test]: number;
}

// wrapper for type&data
interface Action<T extends ActionType> {
  type: T;
  data: ActionData[T]
}

// reduce function type
type ReduceMap<S extends State> = { [key in ActionType]: (state: S, data: ActionData[key]) => S };

// reduce process map (I prefer using object instead of switch)
const reduceMap : ReduceMap<State> = {
  [ActionType.UpdateInterval]: (state, data) => state,
  [ActionType.None]: (state, data) => state,
  [ActionType.Test]: (state, data) => state
};

// just reducer function
function reducer<T extends ActionType>(state: State, action: Action<T>) : State {        
  return reduceMap[action.type](state, action.data);
}
```

And the problem is inside reducer function: typescripts says that second reduceMap function argument has type `never`.
But I expected it to be something like `Interval | undefined | number`.

[image]

`Argument of type 'ActionData[T]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'number | Interval | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)`

I suppose there is a problem when I'm getting data-type from ActionData interface by `key` (at `ReduceMap` type). But I have not sense how to fix it.